# How to display a datatable in the view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, datatable

I have a visual studio windows from called managerForm. Clicking a button on the manager form will bring up a filter form. Also, I have a separate dataGridView Form.

By clicking "SELECT" button on the filter form, I will get a SQL dataTable. I want to display the table on the dataGridView Form.

I don't know how to connect them together. Any help?
dg.myDatagridView.DataSource = filter.returnedDataList; 
In this code, I cannot get the returnedDataList since filter closed.

```
    private void btnDisplayFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filterForm filter = new filterForm();
        filter.ShowDialog(this);

        displayGridViewControl dg = new displayGridViewControl();
        dg.myDatagridView.DataSource = filter.returnedDataList;
        displayGridView.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with using statement

```
private void btnDisplayFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(filterForm filter = new filterForm())
    {
         if(filter.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             displayGridViewControl dg = new displayGridViewControl();
             dg.myDatagridView.DataSource = filter.returnedDataList;
             displayGridView.ShowDialog();
         }
     }
}
```

This will keep the instance of filterForm still available and you could get the public properties of this instance until your code reaches the closing brace of the using statement